# NodeJS File Creation as an Object?

Tags: node.js, file, slack-api

I dont want to save the file locally, but I want to create a file object which is then uploaded through an API.

```
    var request = require("request");
    var fs = require("fs");

    var arr = [
     [4, 56, 7, 3, 345],
     [34, 5, 2, 5, 7]
       ];

    var r = requests.post("https://slack.com/api/files.upload", function(err, res,body){
       console.log(body)''
     }

     var form = r.form();
     form.append('token', token)
     form.append("filename", filename)
     form.append('file', new Buffer(arr));
```

I want to know if its possible to not save the file locally and just add in the file with the data to the form to be submitted through the API?

Comment: How is the file data getting into the code above? Is that supposed to be `file` or `fs.createReadStream('SOMEPATH');`?

Comment: @peteb file.  Sorry the demo I was looking at was a read stream.. So could be either?  Whatever works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pipe the file directly into the request without saving the value. However, it depends on where the data is coming from and how you can access it.
When you do `fs.createReadStream('<filepath>')` you're creating a `ReadStream` that you pass to `request` as part of your form data. Request then uses this Stream to read the file and pass it through to the resource you just requested.

The below code, will take a file that is accessible to the server and will pass it through request to the desired endpoint.

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var formData = {
  token: token,
  filename: filename,
  file: fs.createReadStream('<filepath>');
};

request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
  form: formData
}, function(err, res, body) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(body, null, 2));
});
```

Comment: hmmm I think you misinterpreted the question a bit, may have been my fault.  But I dont want to access the file from a path, instead I was hoping to just add an array of data to a stream which can then be passed into the formData object? So the file with data can be generated dynamically

Comment: When you say an array of data, I'm guessing you mean a byte array? If so you can just use the Buffer class which is part of the Node Core and pass it as `file: new Buffer(yourArray)` where `yourArray` is your byte array.

Comment: makes sense, but can you elaborate more on what you mean by byte array?

Comment: take a look what I am trying as I edited the post. But still no data is being sent.  It says no file data.